# React Webpack file-loader and url-loader not working on Heroku yet working fine locally

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I've made a MERN app that has a carousel of pictures working with 'framer-motion' on react. It works as expected on a local machine however none of the images display when deployed on Heroku.

It initially didn't work locally either but I've added

```
esModule: false
```

in both 'url-loader' and 'file-loader' in webpack.config then it started working fine on local machine but it still is not working on Heroku for some reason. What do I do to fix it?

*react component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions'

const Hero = (props) => {
  // This determines the movement of the div when the page loads.
  const pageVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "-100vw",
      scale: 0.8
    },
    in: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      scale: 1
    },
    out: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "100vw",
      scale: 1.2
    }
  };

  return (
    <motion.div initial="initial"
      animate="in"
      exit="out"
      variants={pageVariants} className="uk-cover-container" id="hero">
      <h1>Welcome to Co-Lab!</h1>

      <h5>Find real-life team members for any project you can dream of.</h5>

      <div id="carousel" className="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabIndex="-1" uk-slideshow="autoplay: true; animation: fade">
        <ul className="uk-slideshow-items">
          <li>
            <Link key="1" to="/profile" > <motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }} className="carousel_button" >Create a Profile</motion.button></Link>
            <img className="carousel_img" src={require("../images/stanley-dai-73OZYNjVoNI-unsplash_optimized.jpg")} alt="typing on laptop" uk-cover="true" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link key="1" to="/createproject"><motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }} className="carousel_button" >Start a Project</motion.button></Link>
            <img className="carousel_img" src={require("../images/jeff-sheldon-8z2Q6XWLYa4-unsplash_optimized.jpg")} alt="desk with notebook" uk-cover="true" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link key="1" to="/searchusers"><motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }} className="carousel_button" >Invite your Friends</motion.button></Link>
            <img className="carousel_img" src={require("../images/michal-parzuchowski-DbnMr3hUYjA-unsplash_optimized.jpg")} alt="hand with chalk" uk-cover="true" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link key="1" to="/searchprojects"><motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }} className="carousel_button" >Find your Calling</motion.button></Link>
            <img className="carousel_img" src={require("../images/benjamin-combs-wuU_SSxDeS0-unsplash_optimized.jpg")} alt="gardening" uk-cover="true" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://weavesilk.com/"><motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }} className="carousel_button" >Have Some Fun</motion.button></a>
            <img className="carousel_img" src={require("../images/perry-grone-lbLgFFlADrY-unsplash_optimized.jpg")} alt="hands all together" uk-cover="true" />
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a className="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous="true" uk-slideshow-item="previous"></a>
        <a className="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next="true" uk-slideshow-item="next"></a>
      </div>
      <h5>Create an account and start searching for your perfect team-mates today.</h5>

    </motion.div>
  )
}

function get_user_data({ auth }) {
  return { auth }
}
export default connect(get_user_data, actions)(Hero);
```

*webpack.config.js

```
module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
            // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
            {
              test: [/\.avif$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                mimetype: 'image/avif',
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),

                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-end
                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
{
              
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'images',
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
```

Comment: What's that `some reason`? By the way, are you using webpack 5? If yes, try Asset Modules https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ instead as `file-loader` and `url-loader` might be deprecated in future.

Comment: I really have no idea why it's not working. I will try upgrading to webpack 5 and see what happens. Thanks for the advice